# How to fit with a broken line in only one of two dependent variables?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, non-linear-regression

Using the `mtcars` data set, I am trying to determine the broken line regression fit of `mpg` as a function of `hp` and `wt`, with breakpoints coming only from `hp`. Here is the code:

```
mpg = mtcars$mpg
wt = mtcars$wt
hp = mtcars$hp

reg = lm (mpg ~ hp +wt)

hp_thresh = 150
wt_thresh = 3

library(segmented)
seg.o = segmented (reg,seg.Z=~hp+wt, psi=list (hp=hp_thresh, wt=wt_thresh))
fted = broken.line (seg.o, term="hp") # mpg fit for hp breakpoints
```

`fted$fit` values do not make sense (compare them to mpg values). I guess there is something simple I'm missing in the usage of the function(s).

**EDIT:**

To clarify further: I am looking to use only the segmented relationship between `mpg` and `hp` still including `wt` in a linear fashion. How can one do that?

I tried using `hp_thresh` in the input for `segmented()` so as to have the broken relationship only for `hp` but I get this error: "A wrong number of terms in `seg.Z` or `psi`".

Comment: Where do `segmented()` and `broken.line()` come from?

Comment: Please do not edit question such that existing answers become meaningless. You first asked about the interpretation of the output of `broken.lines()`. I tried to keep this part and add your clearer question as a clearly marked edit. This way, my answer remains valid as answer for the original question. I will add the answer for the edit now.

Comment: Stibu - I understand, will be more careful.  Please realize that the my clarification is only to the first two lines of question where I specifically ask "trying to determine the broken line regression fit of mpg as a function of hp and wt, with breakpoints coming only from hp".  Appreciate your detailed response. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

You are doing things correctly, but you misinterpret the meaning of the output of `broken.lines()` (in your notation, `fted$fit`). These values should not be expected to agree with `mpg`.

You can keep the linear relationship for some of the dependent variables by supplying to `seg.Z` only those variables, where you want to have a broken line.

### What broken.line() does

You are creating a model for `mpg` as a function of two variables, `hp` and `wt`. The model is piecewise linear for in both these variables. It is important to note that in order to predict a value for `mpg`, you need to specify *both*, `hp` and `wt`.

The function `broken.line()` is used to calculate predictions for `mpg` if one of the variables, specified in the argument `term` is varied. You do that for the variable `hp` as follows:

```
fted = broken.line (seg.o, term="hp")
```

But remember: in order to predict, you also need to specify a value for `wt`. The values you get in `fted$fit` are actually calculated with `wt` kept at zero.

You can check this by using `predict()`, which is the function to be used, when you want to obtain predictions from your model:

```
pred <- predict(seg.o, data.frame(hp = hp, wt = 0))
pred - fted$fit
##  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 
##  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

### Creating predictions from the model

If you want to compare the model predictions with `mpg`, you have to use the same values for both variables, `hp` and `wt`, as for the fit. You can also do this with predict:

```
pred <- predict(seg.o, data.frame(hp = hp, wt = wt))
plot(hp, mpg)
points(hp, pred, col = "red")
```

[image]

As you can see, the values produced in this way agree more or less with `mpg`. It is in this way that you should check the quality of your model, and not by using `broken.line()`.

### Plotting the piecewise linear relationship

You can also look at the piecewise linear relationship between `mpg` and one of the variables. You have calculated these values already in `fted`, but you could also directly plot it from `seg.o` as follows:

```
plot(seg.o, term = "hp")
points(hp, fted$fit, col = "red")
```

[image]

Note that also for `plot()`, you need to specify which variable to vary (here `hp`). The other is again kept at zero. I have also added the points from `fted$fit` to show you that the plot is actually equivalent to what is calculated by `broken.line`.

### Fit a broken line for only one variable

If you want to fit a broken line in only one of the dependent variables and keep the linear relationship for the other(s), you need to only specify those variables in `seg.Z` that you want the broken line for. You asked to have the broken line for `hp` only, which can be done as follows:

```
seg.o2 <- segmented(reg, seg.Z = ~hp, psi = list(hp = hp_thresh))
```

The show that this worked, I predict the model with only one of the variables varied and plot.

**Varying `hp`, keeping `wt` fixed`:**

```
pred_hp <- predict(seg.o2, data.frame(hp = 50:300, wt = 0))
plot(50:300, pred_hp, type = "l")
```

[image]

**Varying `wt`, keeping `hp` fixed`:**

```
pred_wt <- predict(seg.o2, data.frame(wt = seq(1.5, 5.5, by = 0.1), hp = 0))
plot(seq(1.5, 5.5, by = 0.1), pred_wt, type = "l")
```

[image]

As you can see, your model for `mpg` depends linearly on `wt`, but has a broken linear relationship with `hp`.

Comment: Thanks, your detailed response makes sense. But I still am not sure - how do I get the fit when I have two explanatory variables but am interested in getting the segmented relationship for only one but not exclude the second.  Updated original question.